# I am trying to run a function when ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey is 'Current'

Tags: swift, icloud, nsfilemanager

I am trying to download a directory in my app's iCloud ubiquity container and I would like to call a function when it finished downloading. I can get the status like this:

```
func synciCloud(){
    do { try FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: documentsPath)
        do {
            let status = try documentsPath.resourceValues(forKeys: [.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey])
            print(status)
        }
        catch let error { print("Failed to get status: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
    }
    catch let error { print("Failed to download iCloud Documnets Folder: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
}
```

The console prints:

> URLResourceValues(_values: [__C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue:
>   NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey):
>   NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent], _keys:
>   Set([__C.NSURLResourceKey(_rawValue:
>   NSURLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey)]))

What I am confused about is the syntax of NSMetadata and how to execute my function. My first thought was to do something like the code below but I'm not sure how to go about it:

```
if status.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatus == ???? { function() }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `status.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatus` is `URLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatus`. That has three values. `.current` would indicate the file is up-to-date.

```
if status.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatus == .current {
    // it's up-to-date
}
```

Comment: That’s perfect rmaddy, thank you. In your opinion, is this the best way to execute a function after the file downloaded? It means I’ll have to do something like if status.. != .current run this again until it is, then run the function. But this seems a little inefficient. I expect the files to be small but still.

Comment: With this you need to do some sort of polling. I'm not aware of a way to be notified when the download is complete but there may be something for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can also monitor downloading status via `NSMetadataQuery` notifications.

```
let query = NSMetadataQuery()
query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", NSMetadataItemPathKey, documentsPath) // create predicate to search for you files

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: query, queue: nil) { notification in
  for i in 0..<query.resultCount {
    if let item = query.result(at: i) as? NSMetadataItem {
      let downloadingStatus = item.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey) as! String
      print(downloadingStatus)

      if downloadingStatus == URLUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatus.current.rawValue {
        // file is donwloaded, call your function
      }
    }
  }
}

query.start() // starts the search query, updates will come through notifications

// Once we are listening for download updates we can start the downloading process
try? FileManager.default.startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: documentsPath)
```

Comment: Thanks Palli, that's helpful. Would the same method work for listening for when the download completed?

Comment: Yes, it's in the example: `if downloadingStatus == ...` you know that file finished download. You could also monitor progress via `let percentDownloaded = item.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey) as! Double`